# How do you call into an executable from library constructor loaded with LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: c, gcc, ld, shared-libraries, ld-preload

I want to be able to call into an executable from a library that I have preloaded. To do this -

I have a simple executable

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void callme()
{
    printf("callme\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    callme();
    return 0;
};
```

This is compiled with

```
gcc -m32 main.c
```

I now want to preload a library so that `callme` is called before `main`.

preload.c

```
extern void callme();

void preload_init() __attribute__((constructor));
void preload_fini() __attribute__((destructor));

void preload_init()
{
    callme();
}

void preload_fini()
{
    callme();
}
```

This is compiled with

```
gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -shared -o libpreload.so preload.c -fPIC -m32 -ldl
```

So now I have `a.out` and `libpreload.so`

When I try and run this

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libpreload.so ./a.out
./a.out: symbol lookup error: ./libpreload.so: undefined symbol: callme
```

To debug this I have tried

```
LD_DEBUG=symbols LD_PRELOAD=./libpreload.so ./a.out
```

The output from this includes this line

```
13184:     symbol=callme;  lookup in file=./a.out [0]
```

So it looks like its looking in the correct place for the callme symbol.

The output from `nm a.out` includes the following line

```
080483b4 T callme
```

Do I have to compile in such a way that makes callme externally accessible from outside of a.out ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-rdynamic` to your program's compilation flags. By default, only shared libraries are linked with dynamic symbols table (table that dynamic linker (e.g. `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`) uses to lookup function address by its name).

Without dynamic symbols table, you can't use `dlsym` on self binary too.